# checking if function is a part of/which toolbox

Tags: matlab

We have a relatively "rich" matlab installed on our workstations. I now need to send some code to ..., and I'd like to check what toolboxes it requires for it to work properly.

What would be the easiest way to do that ?

How does one find out what toolbox some function belongs to ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see two questions

#### What toolboxes are required for the function I want to send?

You need to generate a [Dependency Report](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2008/02/04/exposing-your-dependencies/). As you can see in the link I've posted, the required toolboxes are listed towards the end.

Another way to get that information is [depfun](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/depfun.html) - this will give you the files your function depends on.

**THIS** is probably what you really want - [depdir](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/depdir.html) - it will list the **dependent directories** of your M-file.

#### What toolbox does my function belong to?

You can get that information with the [which](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/which.html) command - it will tell you where it's located and indicate if it's a built-in function.

Comment: I'll have to look it up to figure how they all work, but I believe, yes, it is exactly what I'm looking for :-) Thanks mate!