# How to find out what toolbox functions a script is using

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I generate a list of function dependencies in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95760/how-can-i-generate-a-list-of-function-dependencies-in-matlab)

I have a third party script that uses the image processing toolbox. As I don't have access to the IPT, I am thinking about replacing functions from the image processing toolbox. The function where the script stops with the error message from the licence manager is `rgb2grey`, so that shouldn't be to hard to replace. But I don't know, what functions come afterwards. It is a big script spanning several folders and files.

What would you recommend?

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/97072/4612 for finding MATLAB dependencies. This will help you find dependencies the script has and which are not met. That might give you a place to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be different approaches, but neither seems to be fully automatic.

I tried `list = depdir('function-name')`  ( 
[checking if function is a part of/which toolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300394/) ), but after more than 1h I canceled it.

I will now try running the profiler and checking all functions by hand with `which('function-name')`. see [How can I generate a list of function dependencies in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95760)